# Permutation and combination(ALREADY SOLVED)

Tags: statistics

Find the number of teams of 11 that can be selected from a group of 15 players if the youngest 2 players and at most one of the oldest two players are to be included

Ans:385

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Posts which contain nothing more than a problem statement (such as your post) are unlikely to receive answers. I recommend giving us some additional context (what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, and so forth) in order to help us guide you to the appropriate help. See "[How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959)" for more useful information.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly...

You can partition your "set" of players into the different groups (youngest, "middle", oldest) which simplifies your problem. We have the...

2 youngest players

11 "middle aged" players

2 oldest players

Now you want 2 out of the 2 youngest players, 1 of the 2 oldest players, and thus 8 out of the 11 "other" players OR  2 out of the 2 youngest players, 0 of the 2 oldest players, and thus 9 out of the 11 "other" players.

The number of possible teams is then: $\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{11}{8}+\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{2}{0}\cdot\binom{11}{9} = 1\cdot2\cdot165 +1\cdot1\cdot55=385$

Comment: Thats not the answer but nice try

Comment: I've got it by using your approach. You have not taken into consideration the at most part which means 1 or 0 of the oldest two player must be included. The answer is (2c2*11c9)+(2c2*2c1*11c8)

Comment: ah, sorry, "at most" one of the oldest players, overread that, sry, edited the answer